# How can I define a record to be indexable by only some of another objects keys with typescript

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an object using the following interface:

```
interface Obj1 {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const instance1: Obj1 = {
    a: "hello",
    b: "world"
}
```

and I want to have another object who's keys are the same as the first and I want to index it's values using the keys of the first, but the value types will be different:

```
type Obj2 = Record<keyof Obj1, number>

const instance2: Obj2 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

That's fine, but how can I make it so I can use only some of the keys from the first like so:

```
// Gives error
const instance2: Obj2 = {
    a: 1,
}
```

I have tried using `Partial<keyof Obj1>` to no avail and now I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use Pick<Type, Keys>, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Comment: `Record<Pick<keyof Obj, "a">, string>` gives a new error

Comment: Just `type Obj2 = Pick<Obj1, "a">`

Comment: Ah gotcha, I know about `Pick` but what if the value types are different in the second object. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
type Obj2 = Partial<Record<keyof Obj1, number>>;

export const instance2: Obj2 = {
    a: 1,
};
```

Comment: Ah of course, I had my partial in the wrong place!